# Rails 3 routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, haml

Ok, I'm relatively new to rails and am working through the book Rails for PHP programmers.  To make things interesting I'm using Rails 3 and haml to work through the book, and the book is written using Rails 2.X and erb so some of the examples are outdated.

To the question:
The route example in the book is

```
map.presentation 'meetings/:meeting_id/presentations/:action/:id',
    :controller => "presentations",
    :action => "show",
    :meeting_id => /\d+/
```

So that was a pre-Rails 3 route.  My adaptation of the above into a Rails 3 route is:

```
match 'meetings/:meeting_id/presentations/:action/:id', :to => 'presentations#show', :constraints => {:id => /\d/}
```

My adaptation works for the destroy action, but not for the edit action... and due to my inexperience I don't know what I'm doing wrong.  From the article here (http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2010/the-lowdown-on-routes-in-rails-3/) it looks like I'm doing it right, but something isn't right.

The `link_to` helpers that produce the urls are as follows

```
= link_to 'edit',   :controller => 'presentations',
                    :action     => 'edit',
                     :meeting_id => presentation.meeting.id,
                     :id            => presentation.id
# Incorrectly Produces: http://localhost:3000/presentations/edit?meeting_id=2&id=1

= link_to 'destroy', {  :controller => 'presentations',
                        :action     => 'destroy',
                        :meeting_id => presentation.meeting.id,
                        :id         => presentation.id },
                    :confirm => 'Are you sure?',
                    :method => :delete
# Correctly Produces: http://localhost:3000/meetings/2/presentations/destroy/1
```

Your help would go a long way to clearing up my routing haziness.  Thanks so much!

**EDIT**

Here's the non-working routes.rb file in its entirety:

```
UserGroup::Application.routes.draw do
  get "presentations/new"
  get "presentations/edit"
  get "sessions/new"
  get "users/index"
  get "users/show"
  get "users/new"
  get "users/edit"
  get "meetings/index"

  match '/meetings/show/:id', :to => 'meetings#show', :as => 'meeting'
  match '/meetings/new', :to => 'meetings#new', :as => 'new_meeting'
  match '/meetings/edit/:id', :to => 'meetings#edit', :as => 'edit_meeting'

  match 'meetings/:meeting_id/presentations/:action/:id', :to => 'presentations', :constraints => {:id => /\d/}

  #default route
  match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
end
```

**EDIT 2**

Thanks to codykrieger I took a look at the rest of the routes file (I know, duh right?).  Apparently, all those get "..." routes are added when using the rails generator and help to make some default connections in the app.  I commented out the `get "presentations/edit"` line and, wonder of wonders, my routing adaptation actually does work.

This works:

```
UserGroup::Application.routes.draw do
  get "presentations/new"
  #get "presentations/edit"
  get "sessions/new"
  get "users/index"
  get "users/show"
  get "users/new"
  get "users/edit"
  get "meetings/index"

  match '/meetings/show/:id', :to => 'meetings#show', :as => 'meeting'
  match '/meetings/new', :to => 'meetings#new', :as => 'new_meeting'
  match '/meetings/edit/:id', :to => 'meetings#edit', :as => 'edit_meeting'

  match 'meetings/:meeting_id/presentations/:action/:id', :to => 'presentations', :constraints => {:id => /\d/}

  #default route
  match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
end
```

I played around with the order of the routes in the file and also found that if I put my route above all the auto-generated routes, without commenting out the `get "presentations/edit"` line, my route still has the intended effect.

This also works:

```
UserGroup::Application.routes.draw do

  match 'meetings/:meeting_id/presentations/:action/:id', :to => 'presentations', :constraints => {:id => /\d/}

  get "presentations/new"
  get "presentations/edit"
  get "sessions/new"
  get "users/index"
  get "users/show"
  get "users/new"
  get "users/edit"
  get "meetings/index"

  match '/meetings/show/:id', :to => 'meetings#show', :as => 'meeting'
  match '/meetings/new', :to => 'meetings#new', :as => 'new_meeting'
  match '/meetings/edit/:id', :to => 'meetings#edit', :as => 'edit_meeting'


  #default route
  match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
end
```

I'm thinking that the latter is the better way to go and I should make my custom routing declarations above the standard generated ones, but I'm not sure.  If someone out there wants to comment on which practice is better, or if it's better to entirely remove the generated ones if I want to specify my own, I'd love to hear it.

Thanks all :)

Comment: What do the rest of your routes look like?

Comment: @codykrieger - in posting the rest of the routes.rb file, I found that my presentations#edit route had already been spoken for via one of the generated routes earlier in the file. Thanks to you, I posted two versions that work and am now wondering about a best practice regarding the generated routes.  Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Sure thing, glad to hear it! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Routing is done on a first match basis (top to bottom) in the routes.rb file.
So you can keep all routes as you have done above if you want, and Rails will use the first one that matches. However, its messy, potentially buggy and totally unnecessary. So the "match..." lines in your code should be enough, and you can remove the "get..." lines.

Furthermore, your "match...presentations...." line has a bug, it should be

```
...{:id => /\d+/}
```

else it will validate only 1-digit length ids.

Finally, as far as your overall routes.rb is concerned, you do not need to do

> link_to 'edit',   :controller => 'presentations',
>                       :action     => 'edit',
>                        :meeting_id => presentation.meeting.id,
>                        :id            => presentation.id

Instead, you should use edit_meeting_path, new_meeting_path etc. For instance

```
<%= link_to "New meeting", new_meeting_path %>
<%= link_to "Edit meeting", edit_meeting_path(@meeting) %>
```

Finally, you should read [Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) for best practices on how to design nested routes etc.

Comment: Thanks Asif :) I'm becoming more familiar with the rails guides and your link is a big help!